# how to put text in front and back in bootstrap progress bar?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I wants to add text in front and back in the bootstrap progress bar like this

5 star ----------------------------------------------- 70%

I am trying to achieve this like

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="progress-1 d-flex flex-row align-items-center">
  <div class="stars">
    <span>5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  </div>

  <div class="progress" style="height: 3px;">
    <div class="progress-bar bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 5%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="percent">
    <span>70%</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I created a snippet from your code but I don't see any progressbar. Can you please edit the snippet so we can see what your problem actually is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope this is what u r expecting.

Just wrap the `progress div` inside `col div`. change `.stars div` and `.percent` element to `span elements`.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/027b364b90.js"></script>
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <span class="stars">
    <span>5 <i class="fa fa-star"></i></span>
  </span>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="progress" style="height: 3px;">
      <div class="progress-bar  bg-success" role="progressbar" style="width: 5%;" aria-valuenow="25" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <span class="percent">
    <span>70%</span>
  </span>
</div>
```